Why is there a bounty delay?
Why is there a delay of two days (or whatever it is) before you can offer a bounty on a question? If someone is that eager to get a question answered, why not let him do it?

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3330/why-cant-i-just-offer-a-bounty-for-a-question-right-off-the-bat although there have been discussions on removing/shortening or making the delay site specific (apparently now available but in integer days) but these requests have, AFAICT, always been declined.

It's time to remove the bounty delay

Originally, the reason for the delay was essentially to stop users from heavily promoting their questions without allowing the normal course of actions (in particular, closure if the question is low quality) to take place.

Why can't I just offer a bounty for a question right off the bat?

It also has the added benefit of preventing people creating sockpuppet accounts, then spending their 'association bonus' bountying (and then self-answering) low quality questions, gifting the bonus to their sockpuppets.

"closure if the question is low quality" There's been a recent change. Since June 2024, the system now allows users to vote to close bountied questions.

@galacticninja - Hence 'originally'
